# Fabric shows project as not migrated to Firebase, but in migration screen it shows as migrated

Tags: crashlytics, google-fabric, fabric.io

I'm trying to migrate my app from Fabric to Firebase. In Fabric dashboard, it shows like this:

[image]

Great. I go to migration screen to migrate, but I see this (the bottom most is the *same* exact app:

[image]

It shows as migrated, even though it's in the list of "not migrated" apps. It says migrated by an admin, and I'm the only admin. I go to Firebase (there are 2 possible accounts that I may have migrated it in the past just in case I don't remember) in my both Google accounts, but it's not there either.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Google firebase is a little slow at times, only out of personal experience. How long have you waited? If its been more than an hour, Id probably contact google support, I dont think SO can do much about an in-site issue. Although, I may be wrong *shrug*

Comment: @Tay waited for what? I can't perform any step that might take time anyway? It doesn't even let me drag my project to the migration list, showing it as migrated while it isn't.

Comment: Also, this is just a suggestion, but if you want a flawless migration, It would be better adapting your project with firebase, firebase is just a wireless hosting application in most cases, and should support running any static API (JS, HTML, CSS, and corresponding Pre-processors)

Comment: In that case, call/contact google support. Im not sure if stackoverflow can solve a problem with google's migration service

Comment: Well, their official site links to stackoverflow with the [google-fabric] tag, that's why I tried here first. Maybe someone had the same problem and I'm missing some bits.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure then, I checked the official docs, however unfortunately, its blocked by my company policy (yeah that's still a thing), so I might not be able to help you much further than recommending official site support.

Comment: I get it. Living in a country that blocks whole websites like Google, Wikipedia, YouTube, Imgur, or Pastebin because of single pages that government finds offensive, I get that policy :) Anyway, I think I'll either contact support or just create a new Firebase (or maybe another non-Google crash reporting tool) project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a UI discrepancy you're seeing. Your app was very likely migrated by a previous account owner, and they did not give you permission to view the app in Firebase. I recommend writing into support at support(at)fabric(dot)io and they will check your bundle ID in the backend and confirm this suspicion.

Comment: There isn't a previous account owner. I am, and have always been, the _only_ account owner, which makes it even more weird.

Comment: I definitely recommend writing into support then, there could be some GCP permissions issue going on here.